# Content not refreshing in Dash / Flask app after Heroku deployment

Tags: python, flask, heroku, plotly-dash

I have a Dash dashboard which is embedded in a Flask app. The app is deployed on Heroku using the Heroku Container Registry.

A python script (`get_data.py`) runs every 10 minutes using Heroku Scheduler. This script calls the Yahoo Finance API for data, creates a chart and saves it as `image.png` (note: the old image is overwritten with a newer file). The Heroku Scheduler job:

```
python app-folder/get_data.py
```

The expected behaviour is that the new image displays when browser is refreshed *or* when the dash interval component updates the content every N seconds.

**This works locally.** When i run the app locally, and manually call `get_data.py`, the new `image.png` is displayed on browser refresh or when the Dash interval component fires a callback periodically to return the new image. Here's how i refreshed the data while app was running locally:

```
docker-compose run website bash -c "python app-folder/get_data.py"
```

Could this be due to the server returning a cached/outdated response, or is there some sort of restriction on Heroku that I'm not aware of?

Edit: For clarity, the app is not being restarted after `image.png` is updated.

This is the Dash dashboard, however I don't think this is where the issue lies:

```
url_base = '/plotlydash/'


def create_dashboard(server):
    dash_app = dash.Dash(
        server=server,
        routes_pathname_prefix=url_base,
        )

    def serve_layout():
        """
        App.layout to a function so it can serve a dynamic layout on
        every page load.

        By default, Dash apps store the app.layout in memory. This 
        ensures that the layout is only computed once at start - 
        Don't want this!
        """
        return html.Div([

            html.Div(id='image-div', children=[]),

            dcc.Interval(
                id='interval-component',
                interval=6*10000, # 10 seconds
                n_intervals=0
            )
        ])

    dash_app.layout = serve_layout

    @dash_app.callback(Output('image-div', 'children'),
                    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])

    def update_image(n):
        img_path = "app-folder/static/images/image.png"
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(
            open(img_path, 'rb').read())
    
        return html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'\
            .format(encoded_image.decode()), style={"height": "600px"})

    return dash_app.server
```

Comment: Heroku file storage is not persistent. Any file you change or create will be lost once the app is restarted. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku

Comment: Understood. However the app isn't restarted, and presumably the new image.png file should be accessible while the app is still running?

Answer (score 0):

The reason new files cannot be located seems to be because [Heroku has an “ephemeral” hard drive](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku), which means that newly uploaded files will not persist on disk when deploying a container on Heroku.

As suggested by Heroku, the solution would be to stead of storing uploaded files to disk, the best practice is to leverage a cloud file storage service such as Amazon’s S3.